# How to add existing WebEment to another WebEment Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to append some existing `WebElement` into another `WebElement`.
 Example:

I got a web element using below code

```
WebElement reviewList = driver.findElement(By.id("review-list"));
```

I got a container using below:

```
WebElement reviewSection = driver.findElement(By.id("reviews"));
```

Now I want to append the reviewList into reviewSection.
I didn't found any way googling.

Can some one provide me some idea/link how to achieve this.

I have also tried it using javascript as below:

```
//get the html 

 String reviewHtml = reviewSection.getAttribute("innerHTML");

JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsx.executeScript("document.getElementById('review-list').getElementById('reviews').innerHTML='" + reviewHtml + "';");
```

But that too is giving me some error `org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break`

Comment: You're looking in the wrong direction - you cannot use the Selenium APIs to manipulate the DOM of the browser's page.  The selenium API can only be used "from outside" the page to read the DOM of the current page, or the cause interactions with it as if it were the user at the browser.  To actually manipulate the DOM of a page, you would need to use Javascript loaded as part of that same page - "inside the page" - to manipulate it. Libraries like JQuery might help.

Comment: It would be great if you can share HTML block,which can let know what you exactly wants to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
jsx.executeScript("document.getElementById('review-list').getElementById('reviews').innerHTML= arguments[0];", reviewHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify the structure of your webpage?

is the element

```
WebElement reviewList = driver.findElement(By.id("review-list"));
```

contains in the container?

```
WebElement reviewSection = driver.findElement(By.id("reviews"));
```

If yes you can use following way:

```
WebElement reviewSection = driver.findElement(By.id("reviews"));
List<WebElement> reviewList = reviewSection.findElements(By.id("review-list"))
```

And you will get List of reviews so in the next step you can use loop or streams to get text.